# Regex to obtain user and IP

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx to extract form thise type of lines the user (USERTOMATCH) and the assigned IP (10.12.10.12). Any help with that? I can't fine the good one...

```
    2015-08-31 00:24:00 - MYDEVICE - [10.120.12.69] USERTOMATCH(SMS_EmpInside)[NC_EMPER] - VPN Tunneling: Session started for user with IPv4 address 10.12.10.12, hostname MYHOSTNAME
```

Comment: Can you find a bad one? Please show what you tried, we're not here to do your work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A per comment:

1. `(\w+)\(`
2. `] - (.*) \d`
3. `address ([^,]+)`

Matching respectively, username, event and IP in the capture groups. Your device being unknown and as I've no divination skill, I can't check it's doc to know what it allow or support...

---

This `(\w+)\(.*?address ([^,]+)` should do [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jW5cT0/2)

The first part capture capture text (a-zA-Z0-9 and _) after space until an opening parentheses, then match anything until address, capture what's after the space until the coma.

This is a basic regex, not dealing with edge cases, but as you didn't provide a large sample I assume your other log entries will match the same format...

Comment: he doesn't want the IP inside `[]`, he wants the IP after `Session started`.

Comment: @Barmar fixed, and updated

Comment: Thanks for that. I forget to explain that I need the regular expression separated. That would be:

One regex for the USERTOMATCH and also one regex for the address (10.12.10.12).

Then, I just see I need  another regex for identifiying the event. Thaat would be, for example, mathing lines containing "VPN Tunneling: Session started for user with".

Comment: @user3139207 why would you need 3 regex ? Capture groups are there for that, if you explain what you wish to achieve and in which language we may help.

Comment: I need 3 separeted regex because is the input format my device asks me, I can't modify that. I have 1 form for each one of the 3 regex.

Comment: @user3139207 updated, but I won't update again with the question as is, clear up your requirements and update your question so it's understandable and the limits are stated.